# Regular expression need to accept +, -, & before @

Tags: ios, regex, titanium

regular expression need to accept `+,-,&` need to accept before `@` in email validation

`([\w-\.]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})` in this regular expression its not accepting.

can any one provide me proper regular expression.

Example:

> demo+wifi-mail&name@gmail.com

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276246/how-to-write-regular-expressions-in-objective-c-nsregularexpression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this one it'l helps you.

```
([\\w-\\.\\+\\-\\&}]+)@((?:[\\w]+\\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})

NSString *phone=@"demo+wifi-mail&name@gmail.com";
NSString *pNRegex = @"([\\w-\\.\\+\\-\\&}]+)@((?:[\\w]+\\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})";
NSPredicate *PNTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pNRegex];
BOOL check=[PNTest evaluateWithObject:phone ];
NSLog(@"%i",check);----> 1
```

Comment: regular expression changed to ([\w-\.\+\-\&}]+)@((?:[\w]+\.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4})  Now it will worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

This `[\w\.]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (I removed the `-` for now). Every character that is within the square brackets is matched by this class. So, your class is matching all letters, digits and underscores (that is done by the `\w` part) and dots.

If you want additional characters, just add them to the character class, e.g. `[\w.+&-]`.

Be careful with the `-` character, it has a special meaning in a character class, either escape it or put it at the start or the end.

**But be aware, your regex is still not matching all valid email addresses, see the links in the comments.**

Single characters (without special meaning) or predefined classes written in a class doesn't make sense, `[\w]` is exactly the same than `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

([\w-.+-\&}]+)@((?:[\w]+.)+)([a-zA-Z]{2,4}) Now it will work!