# How to write regular expression to find and replace words in ios

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

Input string examples are as follows, It may contains white space,

- example 1: abc?contains(\"good\")

  example 2: abc? contains(\"good\")

  example 3: abc ?contains(\"good\")

  example 4: abc ? contains(\"good\")

Answer for all above should be : abc CONTAINS(\"good\")

Note : regular expression have to remove all white space and Question mark and replace small case "contains" with upper case "CONTAINS".

Comment: Check out these links- [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276246/how-to-write-regular-expressions-in-objective-c-nsregularexpression) and [link2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet) might be helpful. If u want particular code for this condition do ping.

Comment: replace `[? ]+contains[(]` with ` CONTAINS(` ?