# regex to not detect hashtag after a character not space

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, hashtag

I am trying to scan for hashtags from NSStrings in Objective-C and I am using regex. I made a test status on Facebook to see what are the valid hashtags as it is where I want to pattern my hashtag detection with. My problem is that my regex is still getting hashtags that are not preceded by a space or comes before an alphanumeric. In `somethin#idfsjoa` the `#idfsjoa` is being detected as a hashtag when it shouldn't be. I am using [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) to test my regex.

How do I check if the "#" does not come after a space"?

**From Facebook:**

[image]

**The NSString:**

```
#face #Fa!ce something #iam#1 #1 #919 #jifdosaj somethin#idfsjoa #9#9#98 9#9f9j#9jlasdjl #jklfdsajl34 #34239 #jkf #a #1j3rj3
```

The regular expression I currently have:

```
(?!\w+)#(\w+)([A-Za-z0]+)
```

Comment: What is the expected results from your string?

Comment: Where's the Obj-C code you're using?

Comment: I didn't put the objective C code I am using since I only need help on the regex statement. I only put Obj-C on the tag to let people know I am using regex with iOS. @l'L'l

Comment: You were too quick on the correct answer; I had an obj-c solution, but didn't have a chance to post. Also on the last hashtag in your example, is it supposed to match?

Comment: It is because I can already get the matching strings from the checking results in Objective-C. My only problem was the regex formula as my own formula still gets an invalid hashtag. You may post your solution still if you want to share so other people can see it someday if they drop by this question, it might help other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to match your criteria:

```
(?:\s|^)(#(?:[a-zA-Z].*?|\d+[a-zA-Z]+.*?))\b
```

Note that the hashtag itself will be the first (and only) capture.

[image: RegexPal screenshot]

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to remove the spaces on the start of the detected hashtags?

Comment: The space is technically "matched" by the regex, but the only the hashtag itself is included in the capture (`(#(?:[a-zA-Z].*?|\d+[a-zA-Z]+.*?))`) part of the expression.  I'm honestly not an Objective-C programmer so I can't tell you the exact approach, but virtually *all* regex engines will let you access captures within the match... which is what you'd want here.

Comment: I think this will do. I'll just trim the spaces on the hashtags.

Comment: Looks like you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9276827/376789

Comment: The statement above could not seem to match "world" in "#hello!#world" which I think should be a valid hashtag. Any suggestion?