# Objective C: How to extract part of a String (e.g. start with 'src=')

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, parsing

I have a string as shown below

```
NSString *imagesource=@"&lt;img src="http://edge.shop.com/edge.shop.com/ccimg.shop.com/250000/255300/255316/products/1142702303.jpg" title="Marley Coffee&amp;reg; Mystic Morning Organic Ground Coffee" alt="Marley Coffee&amp;reg;";
```

How can I select only the text starting with 'src=' (and ends with a space), in this case the source of the image

Comment: Please always explain what you've tried yourself to fix it before asking others to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression, check out this question which explains how to do it.

[How to write regular expressions in Objective C (NSRegularExpression)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276246/how-to-write-regular-expressions-in-objective-c-nsregularexpression)