# NSRegularExpression is not correct working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

please i need your help.
Here i wrote the part of code, and can not find, where is my mistake:

```
NSString *inputString =@"11111111111";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[[a-zA-Z]]*"
                                                                          options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regExpression numberOfMatchesInString:inputString
                                                            options:0
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [inputString length])];

NSLog(@"numberOfMatches=%d", numberOfMatches); 
// here shows  "numberOfMatches = 7"
```

But checked here the result, the answer is incorrect !
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

So question: where is my mistake ?

Comment: How should we know this? You don't tell us what you expect, so we can't know the correct answer.

Comment: I expect that the "inputString" should only be like this: "abs qwer"
There can not be any number, only alphabetical words.
So for inputString = @"111111" the number of mathes should be Zero.

Comment: Then my answer should be close to what you want, except that the space is missing in the char class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting only 7 matches, I think there should be 12. You don't specify any requirements, so I do a bit of guessing:

The problem is your quantifier `*`. It matches 0 or more, means `[[a-zA-Z]]*` it will also match if it finds 0 chars (the empty string) and an empty string will be found before every digit and at the end of the string.

probably it will help you to use the `+` quantifier, it matches 1 or more. So maybe the regex `[a-z]+` is what you want.

Btw. `[[a-zA-Z]]*` is most probably wrong, I think you want `[a-zA-Z]`. The other thing is, when you use `options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` you don't need to specify upper and lower case letters in your character class, `[a-z]` would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the RegularExpression as `[[a-z]*]`

Comment: regularExpressionWithPattern: @"[[a-zA-Z]]*", so where is my mistake ?

Comment: @kokemomuke once change the @"[[a-zA-Z]]*" to @"[[a-z]*]" and check

Answer (score 0):

you can give this a try if your input is 1111...

```
NSRegularExpression * regExpression = [NSRegularExpression 
regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\W-?1?[0-9]{2}(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?\\W"
                   options:0
                     error:&error];
```

for reference you can visit [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392771/2695503)

Comment: The regex pattern i recived from server, and tested that pattern in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, so everything is correct.
The problem is NSRegularExpression is not correct working.