# How to represent nsstring in a general form for search or comparision?

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I have the IP-Address 123.234.1.456:1234.  Is there a way to represent it in a general form of string like how it is done in other languages. for exmaple "*. *. * . * : *", so that I can replace that IP Address wth the any new IP Address.
I want to replace the IP Address that is written in a file with the new IP Address, but don't know how to locate previous IP Address from file.
The file has html code in which IP Address is present, and I want to replace the IP Address present in it with new one.

Currently m using this way:

```
    NSRange startRange = [html rangeOfString:@"http://"];
    NSRange endRange = [html rangeOfString:@"/a.json?"];
    if(startRange.location != NSNotFound && endRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *oldIPString = [html substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startRange.location+startRange.length, endRange.location)];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:oldIPString withString:ipAdressString];
    }
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use components separated by "." then use components separated bt ":"

Comment: I was trying to using the NSRange to get the beginning range of string and end range of string and replacing the ip address. Just wanted a better way. @Wain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the previous ip address using `NSRegularExpression` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478170/regular-expression-in-ios)