# Regular Expression for Amount Entry in uitextField in ios

Tags: ios, regex, validation

Please any one help me achieve this,
I need to implement validation for Amount Text field.
Here's a regex need to allow allows 1-6 digits before and 1-2 digits after the dot.
I had already try with these ways, but I didn't get the solution.

1) http://www.mpatric.com/2012-07-13-fomatting-ios-text-input-on-the-fly
2) [regular expression in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478170/regular-expression-in-ios)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how many invalid and pointless edits have been made on this post... if it doesn't add anything, then don't edit it. It's fine as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked on iOS before, so I don't know about iOS specific behavior for regexes. You could check if this works.

```
^(\d){1,6}\.(\d){1,2}$
```

Comment: Its also not working in some cases like when we enter more than 8 digits at a time.

Comment: That's weird. Is the regex allowing you to enter more than 8 digits before the decimal point?